# Arsclassica and annoying warnings

Tags: warnings, classicthesis

I always get annoying warnings when using `arsclassica` package.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} % KOMA class
\usepackage{arsclassica} % improve classicthesis
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My title}
\author{Myself}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

and the following the warnings that I get:

```
warning: [scrreprt] Usage of package `titlesec' together with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended. I'd suggest to use the package only if you really need it, because it breaks several KOMA-Script features, i.e., option `headings' and the extended optional argument of the section commands . Nevertheless, using requested package `titlesec'
warning: [hyperref] Option `hyperfootnotes' has already been used, setting the option has no effect
warning: [hyperref] Option `pdfpagelabels' has already been used, setting the option has no effect
```

Is there anyone with some idea how to fix this annoyance?
After some trials it looks like it is the `arsclassica` package itself that is generating the warnings.

Comment: I would be annoyed as well, if my editor would show me the warning that way.

Comment: You can silence the warnings or just ignore them. I don't know about the warning from arsclassica, but you can't simply avoid the one from classicthesis.

Answer (score 2):

The author of the koma-script classes has decided to issue a warning about usage of `titlesec` along with them.

However, you are not bound to use `scrreprt` and you can use `book` instead. You need to set the page geometry yourself, but this is already true when `scrreprt` is involved.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{arsclassica} % improve classicthesis
\usepackage[
  includehead,includefoot,
  textwidth=336pt,
  textheight=675pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My title}
\author{Myself}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

There will be another warning:

```
Package classicthesis Warning: Using package "footmisc" with option "flushmargin"
for footnote setup (not 100\% the same as with KOMA).
```

and the warnings by `hyperref` will still be there. There's little you can do about them: when `arsclassica` issues `\hypersetup`, the options `hyperfootnotes` and `pdfpagelabels` have already been set and they can't be repeated.

For the `footmisc` warning you can load `scrextend` (thanks to Johannes_B for the suggestion); the other two warnings can be silenced.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{hyperref}{Option `hyperfootnotes'}
\WarningFilter{hyperref}{Option `pdfpagelabels'}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{arsclassica} % improve classicthesis
\usepackage[
  includehead,includefoot,
  textwidth=336pt,
  textheight=675pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My title}
\author{Myself}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

If you want to use `scrreprt`, you don't need `scrextend` and you can add the following filter:

```
\WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Usage of package `titlesec'}
```

Comment: @Johannes_B Nice to know.